# Memory corruption error while using auto_ptr

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written a sample code to learn working of auto_ptr, but when I am running my sample code I am getting memory corruption.

My sample code is given below..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    IplImage* temp = cvLoadImage("sample.png");
    auto_ptr<IplImage> aptr (temp);
  }
}
```

Following is the error message that I got from the above program:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000008325c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36eb276166]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36eb278ca3]
./a.out[0x400e9b]
./a.out[0x400df7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x36eb21ed1d]
./a.out[0x400cf9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 7879127
```

Can anybody tell the reason for the above error ??

Comment: 1. don't use IplImages, please. the whole c-api is deprecated, and *must* be avoided. 2. use cv::Mat instead, which already acts as a smartPointer on its own. 3. you have to call cvReleaseImage() to free an IplImage, while auto_ptr calls delete.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated too, avoid it.

Comment: As you're trying `auto_ptr`'s behavior, why don't you just use some custom C++ class (your own) or some simple type as `int`?

Comment: I have tried with normal classes, it was working with them

Comment: This is actually a good question. I don't understand why it's not being up voted.

Comment: @karlphillip: It would have been a good question a few years ago. It's now only of interest to linguistic historians, and those working on ossified codebases from previous decades.

Comment: @karlphillip The most outspoken group in the StackOverflow community Are those who are strongly biased toward down votes. "There are no dumb questions... except on Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the comments on [karlphillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip)'s answer, I'm going to update this answer to use, `cvReleaseImage`.

It should be pointed out that you can accomplish this with `unique_ptr` because it will let you specify a custom deleter:

```
unique_ptr<IplImage, void(*)(IplImage*)> aptr(cvLoadImage("sample.png"), [](IplImage* temp){cvReleaseImage(&temp);});
```

This will allow you to use an auto-pointer without changing `cvLoadImage` and still delete the memory correctly.

**EDIT:**

`unique_ptr` is an owning auto-pointer, meaning that it will execute it's deleter to cleanup the allocated memory that it owns: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Unlike `auto_ptr` which always called `delete`, you can pass a custom deleter to `unique_ptr`.

When passing a custom deleter in the `unique_ptr` you need to provide the functor signature to the `unique_ptr`.

So to break my code down:

- `unique_ptr<IplImage, void(*)(IplImage*)>` : This is a `unique_ptr` which will contain an `IplImage*`. The deleter returns `void` and takes an `IplImage*` as an argument.
- `aptr(cvLoadImage("sample.png"),` : This is argument needs to be a manageable pointer which the `unique_ptr` will take ownership of, or a `nullptr`. Obviously `cvLoadImage` is returning the manageable pointer.
- `[](IplImage* temp){cvReleaseImage(&temp);});` : This the custom deleter that I'm passing to `unique_ptr`. I'm wrapping it in a lambda so I can dereference the managed pointer held by `unique_ptr` cause according to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#releaseimage) `cvReleaseImage` needs to take a pointer to the reference to be deleted.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't knew that. Which header is `bind()` from?

Comment: @JonathanMee can you explain the code that you have provided

Comment: @deepak I've edited in hopes of clearing up my code. If that all makes sense great. If you need too much more detail it might be best to start another question. If you need to go that route, post the link here and I'll come over and try to help answer.

Answer (score 6):

`IplImage*` allocated through `cvLoadImage()` **must** be released with `cvReleaseImage()`.

`cvLoadImage()` uses `malloc()` and `cvReleaseImage()` uses `free()` to do the job, while `auto_ptr` uses `delete` (which is from C++).

**You just can't mix `malloc()` with `delete`.**

Comment: As you say they use `malloc`/`free` internally, does that mean you can just call `free`, or is it more complex?

Comment: @Deduplicator, no you can't just call free() on an IplImage. you *must* use the correct cvReleaseImage().

Comment: Great question. Why don't you try it and see if there's a leak? Or maybe you have a few minutes to spare to read the OpenCV source code and understand what `cvReleaseImage()` does. Let us know about your findings.

Comment: In that case, let `cvReleaseImage()` do it's job. By the way, why don't you just change to che C++ API and use `cv::Mat` instead? That C API is going to go away soon.

Comment: I have started my project by using c API, now its very difficult to convert all the functions into c++ API

Comment: It's a day of work. Most method signatures didn't change. And you will see that the code is cleaner, and memory leaks will go away.